# Numpy appending two-dimensional arrays together

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimension

I am trying to create a function which exponentiates a 2-D matrix and keeps the result in a 3D array, where the first dimension is indexing the exponent. This is important because the rows of the matrix I am exponentiating represent information about different vertices on a graph. So for example if we have A, A^2, A^3, each is shape (50,50) and I want a matrix D = (3,50,50) so that I can go D[:,1,:] to retrieve all the information about node 1 and be able to do matrix multiplication with that. My code is currently as

```
def expo(times,A,n):
    temp = A;
    result = csr_matrix.toarray(temp)
    for i in range(0,times):
        temp = np.dot(temp,A)
        if i == 0:
            result = np.array([result,csr_matrix.toarray(temp)]) # this creates a (2,50,50) array
        if i > 0:
            result = np.append(result,csr_matrix.toarray(temp),axis=0) # this does not work
    return result
```

However, this is not working because in the "i>0" case the temp array is of the shape (50,50) and cannot be appended. I am not sure how to make this work and I am rather confused by the dimensionality in Numpy, e.g. why thinks are (50,1) sometimes and just (50,) other times. Would anyone be able to help me make this code work and explain generally how these things should be done in Numpy?

Comment: What is `A`; a small example (not necessarily 50x50) would help.  What's with this `csr_matrix.toarray(temp)` expression?  If `A` is a scipy.sparse matrix, then `A.toarray()` is the right way to create a dense array from it.  And you should only do it once.

Comment: A big part of `numpy` coding is keeping the dimensions straight.  Keep track of them, both in 'theory' and practice.  With `axis` parameter, `np.append` is just `np.concatenate`.  Use that instead.  `np.concatenate([A, B, C], axis=0)` will expect all arrays to have the same number of dimensions.  You can't join 2d with 3d without adjustment.

Comment: If you start with a 2d array, create a new array by joining it and another 2d, with the result being 3d, it will be awkward to `append` another 2d array.  The new 2d has to be expanded to 3d, so dimensions match.  Repeated append/concatenate in a loop is awkward, and slow.

Answer (score 1):

## Documentation reference

If you want to stack matrices in numpy, you can use the [`stack` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html).
If you also want the index to correspond to the exponent, you might want to add a unity matrix to the beginning of your output:

## MWE

```
import numpy as np

def expo(A, n):
    result =[np.eye(len(A)), A,]
    for _ in range(n-1):
        result.append(result[-1].dot(A))

    return np.stack(result, axis=0) 
    # If you do not really need the 3D array, 
    # you could also just return the list


result = expo(np.array([[1,-2],[-2,1]]), 3)
print(result)
# [[[  1.   0.]
#   [  0.   1.]]
#
#  [[  1.  -2.]
#   [ -2.   1.]]
#
#  [[  5.  -4.]
#   [ -4.   5.]]
#
#  [[ 13. -14.]
#   [-14.  13.]]]

print(result[1])
# [[ 1. -2.]
#  [-2.  1.]]
```

## Comments

As you can see, we first simply create the list of matrices, and then convert them to an array at the end. I am not sure if you really need the 3D array though, as you could also just index the list that was created, but that depends on your use case, if that is convenient or not.

I guess the `axis` keyword argument for a lot of numpy functions can be confusing at first, but the documentation usually has good examples that combined with same trial and error, should get you pretty far. For example for `numpy.stack`, the very first example is indeed exactly what you want to do.